# Random path between two coordinates (x, y)

Tags: php, algorithm

I'm working for a game, and I need an algorithm.

I have a grid map, each cell has 2 coordinates : X and Y.

So, for begin, i have a start cell (for example X=8:Y=10), and an end cell (X=18:Y=15).

I need an algorithm that can find me the coordinates(X:Y) for each cells between these two points but with a random path, not in a straight line. With, if it's possible, a maximum number of cells between theses coordinates.

Do you have any ideas?

Edit: you can check http://alex.moutonking.com/wordpress/?p=44, it's my algorithm for a straight line between two coordinates, I need to add a random effect..

Comment: What approaches have you tried so far?

Comment: Try to write an algorythm, then ask the community for help.

Comment: It's all about math and algorithm so you're in the wrong place I guess...

Comment: I have this : http://alex.moutonking.com/wordpress/?p=44, it's my algorythm, but only for a straight line, i need to add a random effect.

Comment: How are you allowed to move from cell to cell? Just one square horizontally / vertically / diagonally? As a first go, try a random walk with a bias based on the current delta x and delta y. That won't give "maximum number of cells" though.

Comment: Are you just trying to make the path random or are there actual obstacles you need to navigate around? And how random do you want it? Meaning, technically randomly, you could go in a spiral until you get to the end.

Comment: Just a random path, with a maximum number (number of cells in straight line + mt_rand(1,10) for example) of cells to avoid spiral and thing like that ^^

Comment: If you just want random movement and don't care about how to get there, I would suggest just doing something like a recursive backtracker maze algorithm and keep going until the algo hits your end point.

Comment: You could also get the general direction of point b from point a and skew the random movement to move in that general direction.

Comment: So if you just got the straight path from A to B using the algorithm on your site, you could just pick a random point on the path, move it in a random direction not already part of the path, fill in the line from previous point to new point and new point to next point. repeat for X number of iterations you would most likely end up with a randomly wavy path that would look like staggering/swerving.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all points then return a random values from the point

```
$pt1 = array(
        8,
        10
);
$pt2 = array(
        18,
        15
);

$sl = new StraightLine($pt1, $pt2);
echo $sl->rand(true);   // return random points
```

Output

```
{
    "x": 16,
    "y": 14
}
```

**To get all points**

```
echo $sl;
```

Output

```
[
    {
        "x": 8,
        "y": 10
    },
    {
        "x": 9,
        "y": 10.5
    },
    {
        "x": 10,
        "y": 11
    },
    {
        "x": 11,
        "y": 11.5
    },
    {
        "x": 12,
        "y": 12
    },
    {
        "x": 13,
        "y": 12.5
    },
    {
        "x": 14,
        "y": 13
    },
    {
        "x": 15,
        "y": 13.5
    },
    {
        "x": 16,
        "y": 14
    },
    {
        "x": 17,
        "y": 14.5
    },
    {
        "x": 18,
        "y": 15
    }
]
```

**Class Used**

```
class StraightLine implements IteratorAggregate, JsonSerializable {
    private $pt1 = 0, $pt2 = 0;
    private $points = array();

    function __construct($pt1, $pt2) {
        if (count($pt1) !== 2 || count($pt2) !== 2)
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Expexting only 2 values each");

        $this->pt1 = array_values($pt1);
        $this->pt2 = array_values($pt2);

        $this->parse();
    }

    public function getIterator() {
        return new ArrayIterator($this->points);
    }

    public function jsonSerialize() {
        return json_encode($this->points, 128);
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->jsonSerialize();
    }

    public function rand($encode = false) {
        $k = array_rand($this->points);
        return $encode ? json_encode($this->points[$k], 128) : $this->points[$k];
    }

    private function parse() {
        $m = ($this->pt1[1] - $this->pt2[1]) / ($this->pt1[0] - $this->pt2[0]);
        $b = $this->pt1[1] - $m * $this->pt1[0];
        for($i = $this->pt1[0]; $i <= $this->pt2[0]; $i ++)
            $this->points[] = array(
                    "x" => $i,
                    "y" => $m * $i + $b
            );
    }
}
```